# Order by in SSRS report

Tags: reporting-services, sql-order-by

My report is supposed to be ordered by completionDate in ascending order. I can get the order in my T-SQL query but when I populate it onto an SSRS report it doesn't seem to carry the order. I'm using SQL Server 2008. and the date is in Varchar. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Avinash.

Comment: +1 for this question helped, but I have added one more solution to this issue

Comment: This is the second question I've found so far about a common SSRS issue that was closed for being "too localized."  The other one was http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7363640/ssrs-only-displaying-first-row but it is open now, and needs some improvement.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Go into the properties of your table (right-click, properties) and set the Sort property to be by completionDate in Ascending order.  You can also Sort each group if you need to.

If you still run into problems, you can sort the field after it's been converted into a date:

```
=CDate(Fields!completionDate.Value)
```

Comment: I tried it.. It doesn't work.. I converted the field into a Date.. it's still not sorted..

Comment: are you adding grouping levels?  make sure all levels are sorted by the same thing.

Comment: make sure the table itself is sorted, before you get to the group.

Comment: Yes.. I have 3 groups within one group.. and there is no sorting defined for any other group.. and yes the table is sorted..

Comment: There is no Details group on my report.. Am I missing something?

Comment: If you view the data, is it sorted the way you want?

Comment: Yes.. when I Exec the store Proc its in the order I want.. I have a rectangle with 4 tables.. the rectangles is grouped by the Project ID and 3 other tables are grouped by Milestones, Risks and issues  within the rectangle.. I want to sort the Milestones group by the completion date.. Some how it refuses to sort the group when I preview the report...

Comment: is your rectangle actually a List?  if so, go in its properties and make sure it's sorted there.

Comment: yes it is a list.. There's no sorting tab in the rectangle's Properties window.. I changed the sorting property on the tablix properties of the rectangle though.. There is no change..

Comment: I changed the sorting property within the milestone Group to Completion Date and it worked.. thank you

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to Nathan I got a fix. I changed the sorting property within the milestones Group to CompletionDate and it seems to be working fine now.. earlier the group was sorted by Milestones.. Just had to change it to completionDate..

Comment: This worked for me to `right-click` the group, and then change the sorting on the group instead of in the table.

Answer (score 2):

You can also **delete** the sorting which is automatically created for you when you do grouping and then you'll get the same `Order` as you get when you execute the Query

becasuse you already got `one sorting in the Query` , so no need to sort it over again in the report

There is nice post over [here](http://www.sqlchick.com/entries/2010/9/11/displaying-fixed-number-of-rows-per-ssrs-report-page.html) regarding grouping which mentions this **deleting**

Your Question helped, but then I went for **Deleting** option which is working fine for me

Comment: This is what I did, the row group was overriding my sort from the query.  Have to check query, tablix, and group.