# SSRS only displaying first row

Tags: sql-server-2008, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have a very basic report in SSRS that displays a grid of data.  The query correctly returns multiple rows but the report only displays the first row.  The query is as simple as SELECT * FROM...  I dont have any special formatting and the tablix is in the details part of the report, not header or footer by accident.  What else can I check?

Comment: Check to make sure they aren't duplicate rows and you have the suppress feature checked.

Comment: They are non-duplicate rows.  I can change the ORDER BY and get the first row of the reversed query, so I know the query is "working".  Where do I find the suppress feature?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The tablix was missing a row group.

Comment: What does this mean, and why did it fix the problem? Why does a tablix need a row group? How did you add one? By providing a more detailed answer, this question is more likely to help future viewers.

Comment: I believe the terminology is "detail row." You can tell which row is meant for details because the left edge of the tablix (the row selector/indicator) will have three horizontal lines. If this is missing, you will want to go to the lowest level Row Group, add a Child Group, and choose the Detail option (or leave the group by specification blank.)

Answer (score 0):

A similar issue is driving me nuts.
I created a report manually from scratch in VS2012, threw a tablix on it and added the columns returned by a simple select. The report preview returns only the first group by primary key.
Then I created a similar report using a wizard and that report, although having only cosmetic differences, returns all groups by primary key.